# How do I combine different groupings of the same data?

Tags: categorical-data, dataset

I'm not sure if I phrased that question correctly or if this is the even the right place to ask, but I'm currently at a loss. For some background, I'm a mobile developer with no real experience in data science, but I'm interested in learning, so I decided to start a side project.

To clarify the question, if I know that weekly, on average, a person watches 21 hours of TV, 25-year-olds watch 20 hours, females watch 23 hours, and white people watch 18 hours. How can I calculate how much television a white, 25-year-old female watches? Is that even possible?

My current thinking is that I find the proportion of each category, compared to the total average ( 20/21, 23/21, 18/21 ), then multiply them all together ( ~.89 ), and finally multiply that by the total average, giving me a value of ~18.78 hours.

Is that right? Or am I completely off-base and making a mockery of statistics?

Comment: Do you have access to the raw data? You basically need a fully interacted regression model.

Comment: @tchakravarty I think?? I'm actually using consumer expenditure data from the Bureau of Labor Statistics, the television example just seemed like an easier way to explain the question. Also, I have no clue what a fully interacted regression model is, so I guess I have some learning to do.

Comment: To help you find relevant portions of an intro statistics text (concerning probabilities of events occurring separately and together), look for statements such as P(A and B) = P(A) * P(B) if and only if A and B are independent.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to CV.

If you want to learn the statistics part of data science, you could start by reading some introductory books and taking some courses, either at a university or at one of the sites that offer them online.

The simple answer to your question is "if that is all you have, you can't solve your problem".  However, as @Tchakavarty alluded to in a comment, if you have the raw data you can run a regression.

But I wouldn't do that now, if I were you. This is too hard a problem for your first problem.

Your first computer program said "Hello World".  You need to start with the basics in statistics, just as you did with programming.